# Notice: Undefined variable

Tags: php, error-handling

i have a problem with this warning

Notice: Undefined variable: T_Person in C:\wamp\www\android_connect\cara1.php on line 35

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\android_connect\cara1.php on line 35

the line 35 is foreach($T_Person as $Person)

i don't understand where is the wrong 
this is my php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Daftar Buku</title>
<!--Bagian CSS untuk Styling Tabel-->
<style type="text/css">
      table, th, td
      {
           border: 1px solid black;
      }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Daftar Buku Terbaru</h3>
<?php

$Person = new SimpleXMLElement('contoh.xml', null, true);


echo "
<table>
<tr>
<th>First name</th>
<th>middle name</th>
<th>Alias</th>
<th>Gender</th>
<th>City</th>
<th>Person ID</th>
</tr>

";

 foreach($T_Person as $Person)
 {
    echo "
 <tr>
 <td width='200'>{$Person->First_name}</td>
 <td width='200'>{$Person->Middle_Name_Person}</td>
 <td width='130'>{$Person->Alias_Person}</td>
 <td width='80'>\${$Person->Gender_Person}</td>
 <td width='130'>{$Person->CityBirth_Person}</td>
 <td width='130'>{$Person['Person ID']}</td>
 </tr>

 ";
 }
 echo '</table>';
 ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You haven't initialised `$T_Person`. Maybe you meant to when you set `$Person = new SimpleXMLElement('contoh.xml', null, true);`

Comment: The error message seems incredibly clear to me.

Answer (score 5):

Because `$T_Person` is not set or not an array. I believe you mean to do this

```
$T_Person = new SimpleXMLElement('contoh.xml', null, true);
```